# Build Github Package as Maven using Jitpack

Tags: git, maven, github

can someone please guide me on how to build github projects using [Jitpack](https://jitpack.io/).

I tried to follow this instruction and always got an error. I forked a project and added some changes on it so I need to get the current commit id as version.

> To get a GitHub project into your build:
>
> ```
> Step 1. Add the JitPack maven repository to your build file
>
>     url "https://jitpack.io"
>
> Step 2. Add the dependency in the form:
>
>     Group: com.github.Username
>     Artifact: Repository Name
>     Version: Release tag or commit id
>
> That's it! The first time you request a project JitPack checks out the code, builds it and sends the Jar files back to you.
> ```

Here is my gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-plugin:1.1.+'
        classpath 'com.stanfy.spoon:spoon-gradle-plugin:0.10.+'
        classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.0'

    //THIS ONE SEEMS NOT TO WORK BASE ON THE INSTRUCTION
    compile ('com.github.username:repo:commitId')
}
```

[this is the project](https://github.com/mightymilk/material-dialogs)

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: something like 'can't resolve com.github.username:repo:commitId'  I tried and update the code and run again. now the gradle process won't stop

Comment: I think i'll just import this manually. I don't know if I've got it but it seems almost an hour the gradle is syncing and doesn't return any message.

Comment: @MightyMilk what is the actual GitHub project that you are trying to use?

Comment: @metrimer this one https://github.com/mightymilk/material-dialogs

Comment: @MightyMilk then the dependency should be `compile 'com.github.mightymilk:material-dialogs:v0.7.2.4'`

Answer (score 15):

The JitPack repository shouldn't be under `buildscripts` in this case. It should be just under repositories:

```
buildscript {
 // same as you have but without jitpack.io
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.0'

    compile 'com.github.mightymilk:material-dialogs:v0.7.2.4'
    // or if you just want the 'aar':
    //compile 'com.github.mightymilk:material-dialogs:v0.7.2.4@aar'
}
```

Repositories for build plugins are placed under `buildscripts` but normal dependency repositories are just placed under `repositories {`.

Comment: I see. ok, let me try this. Thanks

Comment: btw, what if I use the short commit id as the version is this still applicable? I get an error artifact not found

Comment: Failed to resolve: com.github.mightymilk:material-dialogs:v0.7.2.4 :(

Comment: Sometimes it helps to run gradle with '--refresh-dependencies'

Comment: @polasairam seems to be working for me. what's the error?

Comment: @metrimer   https://github.com/siyamed/android-satellite-menu ..  i would like to include that project but i am not able to ...  tried this https://jitpack.io/#siyamed/android-satellite-menu/ff0964c849   , but not working ... it says it didnt resolve

Comment: @metrimer .. was tried it as your answer said and also as webpage said .. but didnt work ..  can you help me pls

Comment: @polasairam perhaps contact the author or open an issue on jitpack. seems like that project is abandoned

Comment: yeah .. i have seen the build log , BUILD FAILED .. so it was showing that it was not resolved

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to import somebody else's repo into yours, or are you trying to make your mightymilk/materialdialogs repo available to other people so they can import it?

**Assuming you are trying to import `mattdesl/lwjgl-basics`:**

The error is here:

    `//THIS ONE SEEMS NOT TO WORK BASE ON THE INSTRUCTION
    compile ('com.github.username:repo:commitId')`

You need to replace:
`username` with the user name on GitHub (e.g. `mattdesl`)
`repo` with the name of the repository you're accessing (e.g. `lwjgl-basics`)
`commitId` with whatever ID you want to use to access a specific commit; AFAIK git tags will work but aren't guaranteed to be stable, a hash *will* be stable though not as nice.

**Assuming you are preparing your own repo for inclusion through Jitpack**

You went to the wrong set of instructions.
See https://jitpack.io/docs/BUILDING for the instructions for your use case.

Answer (score -1):

remove the dependency 'compile......' from gradle,  just add the repository and paste your MPandroid chart jar file in libs folder. This worked for me.